# vixie-cron.x86_64 doesn't seem to execute jobs on crontab

Tags: centos, cron

I have installed crontab on CentOS 5.6 x64 via

`yum install vixie-cron.x86_64`

Here is my crontab -e

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
0       0       *       *       *       cat /root/mysql-backup.txt | xargs /root/mysql-cron.sh
```

Whenever I run this command manually it executes without problems:

`cat /root/mysql-backup.txt | xargs /root/mysql-cron.sh`

I am just wondering why my cron is not running. It's suppose to run every midnight to backup my mysql database.

Are there any other particular steps to configure cron with crontab?

Comment: Stupid question: have you checked that your `crond` (cron daemon) is running?

Comment: Do you have a record of the cron job in your system logs? Do you have local mail configured, so that cron sends you mail if the command produces output? How do you know that the command was not executed in the first place?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez omg .. tsk I am so stupid. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer this question `Stéphane Gimenez` told me to run **crond**. Here is how to do it:

`/etc/init.d/crond start`